# Make controls unselectable

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I wanna make all windows forms controls unselectable with keyboard inputs, because they steal the key events from my form, and the selection box looks ugly, even if i could get the events, so for the first 3 controls i have made the classes that worked

```
class NSButton : Button
{
    public NSButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}
```

but if i wanted to make it for every control in existence, that would be slow, so i tried changing the Button to Control in the code, works fine until i try to create a non-selectable control

```
NSControl control = new Button();
```

it says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.Button' to 'turn_based_rpg.NSControl'

i've tried something along these lines, where the code should return an instance of the input type

```
public T NSControl<T>() where T : Control
{
    return new T();
}
```

but that throws up another error

> CS0304 Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new() constraint

as well, i havent used those things ever, dont have much knowledge of them.
Is there a simple way of making all controls unselectable(possibly programmatically)?

EDIT:
i want it to be able to be converted back to a normal Control, being able to add it to the form's controls with Controls.Add(control)
EDIT2:

```
class NSControl : Control
{
    public NSControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}
```

heres the nscontrol, basically the same as the nsbutton

Comment: I hope you are not talking about other applications that may be running??

Comment: no, i literally mean i do not want the labels, textboxes, etc WITHIN MY FORM stealing focus from the form, when i use the keyboard

Comment: `NSButton control = new NSButton(); this.Controls.Add(control);`. What is `NSControl`? You're using it as a Type, but you have just a method there, which would be: `public T NSControl<T>() where T : Control, new() => new T();`

Comment: Wouldn't it just be `var button = new NSButton();`  Not sure what `but if i wanted to make it for every control in existence, that would be slow,` means.

Comment: the nscontrol is the same as the nsbutton more or less, forgot to paste that part, sorry, edited my question
i cannot convert the Button to a NSControl, therefore i cant set the style in the constructor, cannot add it to the controls

Comment: If you just want to make it unselectable by keyboard, it would be far easier just to set the [TabStop property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.tabstop?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_TabStop) to false.

Comment: "but if i wanted to make it for every control in existence, that would be slow," means that it would take me ten thousand years to make NSButton, NSLabel, NSTrackBar, etc
NS just basically stands for non-selectable

Comment: When you build a Custom Control, it's added to the ToolBox. Use these Control when you design a Form that needs them. - Or replace all existing instances of `Button` with `NSButton` in that Form (CTRL+H). -- Or override `ProcessCmdKey` -- Or implement `IMessageFilter` in your Form, so it gets all messages before they're dispatched to its child Controls. --- You should probably describe a bit better what problem you're trying to solve instead of asking to patch the method you came up with trying to solve it.

Comment: _"because they steal the key events from my form"_ - and if using [`KeyPreview`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview)?

Comment: never heard about keypreview, i think that will be handy, thanks